# Best way to don't draw part of model

Tags: opengl

I am using `VAOs` and shaders to draw my objects on screen. Now I'am faced with situation when I have to hide some part of pre-created buffer.

For example, I have 6 points (3 x 6 = 18 `floats`) in `VBO` with ID = 1; each 3 points represent, for example, one triangle and share same ID.

Points:

```
1, 2, 3,     // 
4, 5, 6,     // This 9 floats share common ID = 1
7, 8, 9,     // 

10, 11, 12,  //
13, 14, 15,  // ... and this floats have ID = 2
16, 17, 18   //
```

Now I have to hide all point with ID = 2. But I don't want to refill VBO. It's to time consuming operation.

I was thinking about pushing into buffer not only points positions, but also their IDs. And then, in fragment shader, discard specified points by their ID. As far as I know, it can be done by passing IDs as vertex attribute pointer, but I don't know how it can be implemented in code.

Please, give some ideas how to hide a part of `VBO`. (if it possible, provide little sample).

Comment: Just draw 3 vertices beginning at vertex 0. The fact that there are extra vertices in your buffer will not bother GL one bit. If you wanted to draw ID 2 instead of ID 1, you could draw three vertices beginning at 3.

Comment: It looks like not too handy when buffer contains a lot of points. What is the best practice to hide part of data while drawing?

Comment: Well, if your buffer is not a contiguous collection of triangles, your only other option is indexed rendering.

Comment: You mean to use "DrawElements" function?

Comment: But how indexes array should looks like? Points array: {1, 2, 3,.... up to 18} and ids array: {1, 2} or what?

Comment: hm... it's still not clear for me. what I really cannot understand how can I find common points to form indexes array when I have, for example, 100K of triangle strips.

Comment: Aside from having to insert primitive restart indices (to use separate triangle strips like that) it should be pretty straightforward. Triangles in strip order are just as efficient vertex cache wise, and do not require the extra primitive restart index. I would suggest not using triangle strips for this.

Comment: thanks for help. everything points that I have to dig deeper into indexed drawing

Answer (score 1):

if the parts you want to hide are known then you can create an index buffer and put the indices of the parts you want to hid at the end of the element buffer and just draw less points:

array buffer:

```
1.0, 2.0, 3.0,  // ID = 1
4.0, 5.0, 6.0,  // ID = 2
7.0, 8.0, 9.0   // ID = 3
```

element buffer:

```
1,3,2
```

then when you want to hide point 2 you only draw 2 elements instead of the usual 3

Comment: sorry, I just have changed my question one minute ago. previous one is not really what I need to get. Look up my new edits.

Comment: @frankie point still stands, move the part you don't want to draw all the time to the end of the buffer and draw less

Comment: I am avoiding use of elements buffer cause It's hard to maintain them with for a huge number of points (what I actually have). Plus, with elements array I have to change data in it. Are any other variants of solving this problem?